# Is it possible to mock newly created instances for a given class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have a class that takes in a configuration object as a parameter of the constructor and then creates new objects in the constructor using that configuration. So generally, is it possible to mock the newly created object without explicit dependency injection?

Relevant portions of the code are:

```
public class Manager
{
    List<Config> _configList;
    List<StateObject> _stateObjectList;

    public Manager(List<Config> configList)
    {
        _configList = configList;

        foreach (config in _configList)
        {
           _stateObjectList.Add(new StateObject(config));
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, can I somehow mock the returned new `StateObject` inside the foreach loop in the constructor?

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 with Moq 4.10 if its relevant

Comment: What exactly do you want to mock and why do you want to mock it? Please [edit] your question to include the test cases you have and explain in detail what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can mock `new` operator in C#, but you can slightly refactor your code and move a creation of `StateObject` into separate class (and create an interface for that)

```cs
public interface IStateObjectFactory
{
    StateObject Create(Config config);
}

public class StateObjectFactory : IStateObjectFactory
{
    public StateObject Create(Config config)
    {
        return new StateObject(config);
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it to a `Manager` class

```cs
public Manager(List<Config> configList, IStateObjectFactory factory)
{
    _configList = configList;

    foreach (var config in _configList)
    {
        _stateObjectList.Add(factory.Create(config));
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to easily mock `IStateObjectFactory` interface with any desired behavior. I don't think that it's possible without injecting this dependency into `Manager` class.